# XNA "out of memory exception" Designing a replay option

Tags: c#, xna

There is a problem "out of memory exception" when exucuting this code. The code takes rapid photos of the main board and stores it to be recompiled into a movie later.

If there is another way to make a replay of the field it would be much appreciated as now I have to take pictures of the board then recompile it into a avi movie.
Any help please.

```
 public class JSTART_Main : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    private GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private Texture2D background;
    private Rectangle mainFrame;
    private SpriteFont font;

    private bool finished = false;
    private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    private Navigation navigation;

    public JSTART_Main()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
        navigation = new Navigation();
        navigation.graphics = graphics;
        navigation.window = Window;
        navigation.CreateClasses();

        //this.graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        this.IsMouseVisible = true;

        navigation.controls.CreateControls();
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_screenshots);

    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();         
    }
    void bw_screenshots(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;


            capture();
            capture();

            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;

            }
            else
            {
                bw.Dispose();

            }              
        }
    void capture()
    {

        while (finished == false)
        {              
                count += 1;
                string counter = count.ToString();

                int w = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth;
                int h = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight;

                //force a frame to be drawn (otherwise back buffer is empty) 
                Draw(new GameTime());

                //pull the picture from the buffer 
                int[] backBuffer = new int[w * h];
                GraphicsDevice.GetBackBufferData(backBuffer);

                //copy into a texture 
                Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, w, h, false, GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat);
                texture.SetData(backBuffer);                
                    //save to disk 
                    Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(counter + ".jpg");

                    texture.SaveAsJpeg(stream, w, h);
                    stream.Flush();
                    stream.Close();
                    texture.Dispose();

             }

    }
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Background");
        mainFrame = new Rectangle(0, 0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("font");

    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }
    int count = 0;

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        //if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        //this.Exit();
        foreach (Unit enemy in navigation.players.enemies.Values)
        {
            enemy.EnemyAI(navigation.aiCollision);
        }
        navigation.input.UpdateKeyboard();
        navigation.networking.Receive();
        navigation.players.SpotEnemy();
        navigation.input.UpdateMouse();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        try
        {
            base.Draw(gameTime);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(background, mainFrame, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "X: " + navigation.players.server.pos.X.ToString() + "\nY: " + navigation.players.server.pos.Y.ToString(), new Vector2(22, 22), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
            navigation.players.server.LoadContent(Content);
            navigation.players.server.Draw(spriteBatch, Color.Transparent);
            foreach (MainObject map in navigation.players.map)
            {
                map.LoadContent(Content);
                map.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }

            foreach (Unit enemy in navigation.players.enemies.Values)
            {
                if (navigation.controls.cbxShowEnemies.Checked || enemy.visible == true)
                {
                    enemy.LoadContent(Content);
                    enemy.Draw(spriteBatch, Color.Red);
                }
            }

            foreach (Unit unit in navigation.players.players.Values)
            {
                if (unit != null && unit.visible)
                {
                    unit.LoadContent(Content);
                    unit.Draw(spriteBatch, Color.White);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception )
        { }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you where able to draw the game and board once, surely you could do it another time. All you have to do is store the moves made by each unit, and just replay that.

If you are trying to save it to an avi file consider writing each frame to the harddisk instead of saving them in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you store into RAM all your scene frames, your likely to to end your memory quite soon, try to do this calculation:

```
number_of_frame_stored * frame_height* frame_width * 32 = ....
```

So periodically dump your stored frames to disk and ensure that the previously allocated memory will be freed (garbage collected).

I see another issue on your code: you are doing several LoadContent inside the main Draw method. Disk access maybe a bottleneck, so try to load all contents you need when your game starts.

Comment: thanks but the frames is already being written to the disk:  Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(counter + ".jpg");

                    texture.SaveAsJpeg(stream, w, h);

Comment: and i just need a way to clear the frames that is tored in the ram. thanks for tip on loadContent it already made a bottleneck. code is still sloppy but will fix it now.

Comment: Okay you say to load all content when game start? Some content can only be loaded once the board is updated or new object is placed on board or a player logs in and is displayed on the the board. What content should be loaded at start then?

Comment: Well, I don't see all your LoadContent code, and I don't know your game logic. btw for content I mean texture, meshes and so on. This stuff should be loaded when the program starts, not inside your Draw method.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help much appreciated only prob still is out of memory need a way to clear or ".dispose()" the texture somehow. Force calling the GC does not help and closing and restarting the background thread also no result.